# The disappearance of a variable if it is not displayed Rust

Tags: rust

Please help me to understand why i need to display variable. I use ssh2 crate to create ssh connect.
My code is here:

```rust
use ssh2::Session;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::{TcpStream};

fn main() {
  // Connect to the SSH server
  let tcp = TcpStream::connect("192.168.1.251:22").unwrap();
  let mut sess = Session::new().unwrap();
  sess.set_tcp_stream(tcp);
  sess.handshake().unwrap();
  sess.userauth_password("root", "password").unwrap();

  let mut s = String::new();
  let last_stat = String::from("unknown"); 

  loop {
    let mut channel = sess.channel_session().unwrap();
    channel.exec("systemctl is-active firewalld").unwrap();
    channel.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
    if &s.to_string().trim() == &last_stat {
      print!("stopped");
    } else {
      print!("{}",&s);    
    }
    &s.clear();
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
  }
}
```

If the firewallв is stopped, nothing is displayed. But if I show the variable in the output, then the code works and display "unknown".

```
use ssh2::Session;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::{TcpStream};

fn main() {
  // Connect to the SSH server
  let tcp = TcpStream::connect("192.168.1.251:22").unwrap();
  let mut sess = Session::new().unwrap();
  sess.set_tcp_stream(tcp);
  sess.handshake().unwrap();
  sess.userauth_password("root", "password").unwrap();

  let mut s = String::new();
  let last_stat = String::from("unknown"); 

  loop {
    let mut channel = sess.channel_session().unwrap();
    channel.exec("systemctl is-active firewalld").unwrap();
    channel.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
    if &s.to_string().trim() == &last_stat {
      print!("{}",&s);
    } else {
      print!("{}",&s);    
    }
    &s.clear();
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
  }
}
```

Why i must display variable &s to code works?
many thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: output is line buffered, there's a newline in the input stream, and `print!` doesn't flush the output. Try `println!("stopped")` instead of `print!` and see if that fixes it

Comment: Thanks! it works!